# How can I use slider on grouped data to get mean and sd of irregular rolling window?

Tags: r, dplyr, slider, mean, rolling-computation

### **EDIT:** I was able to find a solution to the problem, see the end of the post.

I want to get the rolling calculation of mean, sd, and counts within discrete time periods (months). I want each mean and sd to be calculated from the current month and some number of previous months (back 1 month in the below example, real code is a large dataset that will go back 120 months). The unique RESULTs have to be grouped by REGION and TYPE. *Months have varying number of entries which is where I run into problems because the rolling "window" has to change for each month.*

```
  REGION  PLACE   TYPE       DATE       RESULT
1  3226H5     1   Type B    2017-05-01   0.10
2  3226H5     2   Type B    2017-05-01   0.12
3  3226H5     1   Type B    2017-06-05   0.17
4  3226H5     2   Type B    2017-06-05   0.18
5  3226H5     1   Type B    2017-07-10   0.11
6  3226H5     2   Type B    2017-07-10   0.11


library(slider)
library(tidyverse)

my_data <- structure(list(REGION = c("3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", 
"3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", 
"3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", 
"3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", 
"3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3226H5", "3285", "3285", 
"3285", "3285", "3285", "3285", "3285", "3285", "3285", "3285", 
"3285", "3285", "3285", "3285", "3285", "3285", "3285", "3285", 
"3285"), PLACE = c("1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", 
"2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", 
"1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "3", "4", "3", "4", "3", 
"4", "3", "4", "3", "4", "3", "4", "4", "3", "4", "3", "4", "3", 
"4"), TYPE = c("Type B", "Type B", "Type B", "Type B", "Type B", 
"Type B", "Type B", "Type B", "Type B", "Type B", "Type A", "Type A", 
"Type A", "Type A", "Type A", "Type A", "Type A", "Type A", "Type A", 
"Type A", "Type C", "Type C", "Type C", "Type C", "Type C", "Type C", 
"Type C", "Type C", "Type C", "Type C", "Type B", "Type B", "Type B", 
"Type B", "Type B", "Type B", "Type B", "Type B", "Type B", "Type B", 
"Type C", "Type C", "Type C", "Type C", "Type C", "Type C", "Type C", 
"Type C", "Type C"), DATE = structure(c(1493596800, 1493596800, 
1496620800, 1496620800, 1499644800, 1499644800, 1502064000, 1502064000, 
1506297600, 1506297600, 1493596800, 1493596800, 1496620800, 1496620800, 
1499644800, 1499644800, 1502064000, 1502064000, 1506297600, 1506297600, 
1493596800, 1493596800, 1496620800, 1496620800, 1499644800, 1499644800, 
1502064000, 1502064000, 1506297600, 1506297600, 1493596800, 1493596800, 
1496620800, 1496620800, 1499644800, 1499644800, 1502064000, 1502064000, 
1506297600, 1506297600, 1493596800, 1493596800, 1496620800, 1499644800, 
1499644800, 1502064000, 1502064000, 1506297600, 1506297600), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), RESULT = c(0.1, 0.12, 0.17, 0.18, 0.11, 0.11, 0.05, 
0.08, 0.1, 0.22, 2.84, 3.18, 2.22, 3.88, 2.35, 2.68, 3.39, 4.96, 
5.15, 6.37, 0.01, 0.06, 0.05, 0.07, 0.01, 0.08, 0.01, 0.34, 0.04, 
0.28, 0.02, 0.12, 0.18, 0.37, 0.02, 0.61, 0.08, 0.13, 0.2, 0.59, 
0.03, 0.08, 0.05, 0.14, 0.13, 0.37, 0.22, 0.22, 0.16)), row.names = c(NA, 
-49L), class = "data.frame")
```

After not getting the variable rolling window with zoo:rollmean [(my previous post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75213295/calculate-rolling-mean-and-rolling-sd-of-grouped-time-series-data-with-different) I am trying to use slider(), either slide_period_dfr or slide_index_dbl.

The below is correctly getting the mean and sd, but I want the count and I want it grouped by REGION and TYPE for 1 rolling mean per month (the first month doesn't need to be rolling).

```
mutateTable <- my_data %>%
  arrange(DATE) %>%
  mutate(
    monthly = floor_date(DATE, "month"),
    mean = slide_index_dbl(RESULT, DATE, mean, .before = months(1)),
    sd = slide_index_dbl(RESULT, DATE, sd, .before = months(1)))

mutateTable
 REGION PLACE   TYPE       DATE RESULT    monthly      mean       sd
1  3226H5     1 Type B 2017-05-01   0.10 2017-05-01 0.6560000 1.243867
2  3226H5     2 Type B 2017-05-01   0.12 2017-05-01 0.6560000 1.243867
3  3226H5     1 Type A 2017-05-01   2.84 2017-05-01 0.6560000 1.243867
4  3226H5     2 Type A 2017-05-01   3.18 2017-05-01 0.6560000 1.243867
5  3226H5     1 Type C 2017-05-01   0.01 2017-05-01 0.6560000 1.243867
6  3226H5     2 Type C 2017-05-01   0.06 2017-05-01 0.6560000 1.243867
7    3285     3 Type B 2017-05-01   0.02 2017-05-01 0.6560000 1.243867
8    3285     4 Type B 2017-05-01   0.12 2017-05-01 0.6560000 1.243867
```

I tried to use summarise within a function but it doesn't work unless I arrange it by DATE, and then groupings are ignored.

```
summariseTable <- function(DATE) {
  summarise(my_data, start = min(DATE), end = max(DATE), mean = mean(RESULT), sd = sd(RESULT), count=n(), count=cur_group_rows())
}

my_data <- my_data %>% 
  arrange(DATE)

slide_period_dfr(
  my_data,
  my_data$DATE,
  "month",
  summariseTable
)
     start        end      mean       sd count
1   2017-05-01 2017-09-25 0.8761224 1.568644     1
2   2017-05-01 2017-09-25 0.8761224 1.568644     2
3   2017-05-01 2017-09-25 0.8761224 1.568644     3
4   2017-05-01 2017-09-25 0.8761224 1.568644     4
5   2017-05-01 2017-09-25 0.8761224 1.568644     5
```

Any help? I want to end with a table that looks like this, where the mean and sd are calculating the Results from current month AND previous month:

```
my_data %>%
  filter(REGION == "3226H5" & TYPE == "Type B")
      REGION  TYPE      month   rolling_mean    sd    count
#> 3  3226H5  Type B  2017-05-01       0.110   0.01    2
#> 4  3226H5  Type B  2017-06-01       0.143   0.033   4
#> 5  3226H5  Type B  2017-07-01       0.143   0.033   4
#> 5  3226H5  Type B  2017-08-01       0.088   0.025   4
```

---

### **So with the help of @Jon-Spring replies I was able to solve this using the below code/workaround.**

First I used 'add_count' to get the count of entries for each date which is important to make sure the code is working and SDs are correct. Then I used slide_index_dbl to get the rolling means and this produced data with duplicates for each month. Then I cheated and used 'slice(seq_len(1))' to take the first entry for each month, since the rolling_mean and rolling_sd are the same.

The table with duplicates:

```
 REGION PLACE TYPE   DATE                RESULT new_cases rolling_mean rolling_sd
   <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <dttm>               <dbl>     <int>        <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 3226H5 1     Type A 2017-05-01 00:00:00   2.84         2         3.70      1.37 
 2 3226H5 2     Type A 2017-05-01 00:00:00   3.18         2         3.70      1.37 
 3 3226H5 1     Type A 2017-06-05 00:00:00   2.22         2         3.88      1.50 
 4 3226H5 2     Type A 2017-06-05 00:00:00   3.88         2         3.88      1.50
```

The final table:

```
REGION PLACE TYPE   DATE                RESULT new_cases rolling_mean rolling_sd
  <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <dttm>               <dbl>     <int>        <dbl>      <dbl>
1 3226H5 1     Type A 2017-05-01 00:00:00   2.84         2         3.70      1.37 
2 3226H5 1     Type A 2017-06-05 00:00:00   2.22         2         3.88      1.50 
3 3226H5 1     Type A 2017-07-10 00:00:00   2.35         2         4.15      1.59 
4 3226H5 1     Type A 2017-08-07 00:00:00   3.39         2         4.97      1.22
```

The final code:

```
grouped_roll <- my_data2 %>%
  add_count(WBID, PARAMETER, DATE, name = "new_cases") %>%

  arrange(WBID, PARAMETER, DATE) %>%   
  
  group_by(WBID, PARAMETER)    %>%        
    
  mutate(                               
    rolling_mean = slide_index_dbl(RESULT,
      .i = DATE,      # index on date 
      .f = mean,                      
      .after = months(6)),             
    rolling_sd = slide_index_dbl(
      RESULT,
      .i = DATE,
      .f = ~ sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE),
      .after = months(6)
    )
  )

grouped_roll <- grouped_roll %>%
  group_by(DATE) %>%
  slice(seq_len(1))
grouped_roll
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by rolling window. Do you actually want mean, sd, count per region/type/month? Is the output numerically correct or just in the form you expect? I ask b/c in your sample data there are only two Type A in May, with RESULTS around 3, not 0.10.

Comment: I have now fixed the numbers, hopefully that helps.

Comment: How does the cumulative count stay the same rolling from three to four months (both 4), but the mean and sd change?

Comment: Because the cumulative count is curently only going back 1 month. Each month in this example has 2 entries so the first month only has itself (2) and then the next months have (4)

Comment: Is your goal that the rolling period SHOULD include everything back to the start, or you want to control how long the rolling period goes back and that could be a variable ranging from its current value of 1 month up to optionally 120 months?

Comment: I would like to control the rolling period exactly, its a dataset of about 50 years so I would like to go back up to 10 years (120 months)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form of your output makes it sound like you might be looking for monthly mean/sd/n per REGION/TYPE. That could be:

```
my_data %>%
  group_by(REGION, TYPE, 
           month = as.Date(lubridate::floor_date(DATE, "month"))) %>%
  summarize(mean = mean(RESULT),
            sd = sd(RESULT),
            n = n(), .groups = "drop")
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 25 × 6
   REGION TYPE   month       mean      sd     n
   <chr>  <chr>  <date>     <dbl>   <dbl> <int>
 1 3226H5 Type A 2017-05-01 3.01  0.240       2
 2 3226H5 Type A 2017-06-01 3.05  1.17        2
 3 3226H5 Type A 2017-07-01 2.52  0.233       2
 4 3226H5 Type A 2017-08-01 4.18  1.11        2
 5 3226H5 Type A 2017-09-01 5.76  0.863       2
 6 3226H5 Type B 2017-05-01 0.11  0.0141      2
 7 3226H5 Type B 2017-06-01 0.175 0.00707     2
 8 3226H5 Type B 2017-07-01 0.11  0           2
 9 3226H5 Type B 2017-08-01 0.065 0.0212      2
10 3226H5 Type B 2017-09-01 0.16  0.0849      2
# … with 15 more rows
```

---

EDIT:

To get the rolling metrics, with one per month, we could calculate the rolling metrics and filter for just the last observation each month per REGION/TYPE:

```
library(slider)
my_data %>%
  arrange(DATE) %>%
  group_by(REGION, TYPE) %>%
  mutate(mean = slide_dbl(RESULT, mean, .before = Inf),
            sd = slide_dbl(RESULT, sd, .before = Inf),
            n = slide_dbl(RESULT, ~sum(.x == .x), .before = Inf)) %>%
  # Note: If you want the rolling window to have a max width of, say,
  #    120 months, you might want to first floor_date(DATE, "month") and
  #    then use slide_index_dbl(... .before = ~.x %m-% months(119)) 
  mutate(month = floor_date(DATE, "month")) %>%
  group_by(REGION, TYPE, month) %>%
  slice(n())
```

Result

```
   REGION PLACE TYPE   DATE                RESULT  mean     sd     n month              
   <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <dttm>               <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dttm>             
 1 3226H5 2     Type A 2017-05-01 00:00:00   3.18 3.01  0.240      2 2017-05-01 00:00:00
 2 3226H5 2     Type A 2017-06-05 00:00:00   3.88 3.03  0.692      4 2017-06-01 00:00:00
 3 3226H5 2     Type A 2017-07-10 00:00:00   2.68 2.86  0.608      6 2017-07-01 00:00:00
 4 3226H5 2     Type A 2017-08-07 00:00:00   4.96 3.19  0.901      8 2017-08-01 00:00:00
 5 3226H5 2     Type A 2017-09-25 00:00:00   6.37 3.70  1.37      10 2017-09-01 00:00:00
 6 3226H5 2     Type B 2017-05-01 00:00:00   0.12 0.11  0.0141     2 2017-05-01 00:00:00
 7 3226H5 2     Type B 2017-06-05 00:00:00   0.18 0.143 0.0386     4 2017-06-01 00:00:00
 8 3226H5 2     Type B 2017-07-10 00:00:00   0.11 0.132 0.0343     6 2017-07-01 00:00:00
 9 3226H5 2     Type B 2017-08-07 00:00:00   0.08 0.115 0.0431     8 2017-08-01 00:00:00
10 3226H5 2     Type B 2017-09-25 00:00:00   0.22 0.124 0.0510    10 2017-09-01 00:00:00
# … with 15 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! That is exactly what I want, but I also want the mean/sd/n for the current month AND all previous months in a specified window. So if it makes more sense that my post example: beside that table you made I want columns Rolling_mean, Rolling_sd, and Rolling_count, where Rolling_count is the number of entries from the current month + the previous month (4). I have updated my post to clarify

Comment: Updated. I don't love my approach but I think it gets what you're looking for.

Comment: could you clarify on getting the max width of the rolling window, I tried to add it with a roll of 2 and getting unexpected symbol. In your table the mean and sd are correct for the single month rolling, and interesting the RESULT is just the last entry of the month. THANK YOU for your answer

Answer (score 0):

### **So with the help of @Jon-Spring replies I was able to solve this using the below code/workaround.**

First I used 'add_count' to get the count of entries for each date which is important to make sure the code is working and SDs are correct. Then I used slide_index_dbl to get the rolling means and this produced data with duplicates for each month. Then I cheated and used 'slice(seq_len(1))' to take the first entry for each month, since the rolling_mean and rolling_sd are the same.

The table with duplicates:

```
 REGION PLACE TYPE   DATE                RESULT new_cases rolling_mean rolling_sd
   <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <dttm>               <dbl>     <int>        <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 3226H5 1     Type A 2017-05-01 00:00:00   2.84         2         3.70      1.37 
 2 3226H5 2     Type A 2017-05-01 00:00:00   3.18         2         3.70      1.37 
 3 3226H5 1     Type A 2017-06-05 00:00:00   2.22         2         3.88      1.50 
 4 3226H5 2     Type A 2017-06-05 00:00:00   3.88         2         3.88      1.50
```

The final table:

```
REGION PLACE TYPE   DATE                RESULT new_cases rolling_mean rolling_sd
  <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <dttm>               <dbl>     <int>        <dbl>      <dbl>
1 3226H5 1     Type A 2017-05-01 00:00:00   2.84         2         3.70      1.37 
2 3226H5 1     Type A 2017-06-05 00:00:00   2.22         2         3.88      1.50 
3 3226H5 1     Type A 2017-07-10 00:00:00   2.35         2         4.15      1.59 
4 3226H5 1     Type A 2017-08-07 00:00:00   3.39         2         4.97      1.22
```

The final code:

```
grouped_roll <- my_data2 %>%
  add_count(WBID, PARAMETER, DATE, name = "new_cases") %>%

  arrange(WBID, PARAMETER, DATE) %>%   
  
  group_by(WBID, PARAMETER)    %>%        
    
  mutate(                               
    rolling_mean = slide_index_dbl(RESULT,
      .i = DATE,      # index on date 
      .f = mean,                      
      .after = months(6)),             
    rolling_sd = slide_index_dbl(
      RESULT,
      .i = DATE,
      .f = ~ sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE),
      .after = months(6)
    )
  )

grouped_roll <- grouped_roll %>%
  group_by(DATE) %>%
  slice(seq_len(1))
grouped_roll
```